# Nginx proxy server to S3 static website based on domain name

Tags: nginx

How to use NGINX `proxy_pass` to redirect to an S3 static web site?

`http://subdomain.mydomain.com` should be proxied to `http://subdomain.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com`

One important requirement is `subdomain` has to be **dynamic** (which means need to use variables)

Below example works without variables:

```
server {
   server_name sudomain.mydomain.com;
   location / {
       proxy_pass http://subdomain.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com
   }
}
```

Comment: When you use variables as part of domain name in your `proxy_pass` directive, you also need to specify a [`resolver`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver) directive within your configuration. You can use your local name server if you have one, or use something external like Google public DNS (8.8.8.8) or DNS provided for you by your ISP. You can read some additional technical information [here](http://www.nginx-discovery.com/2011/05/day-51-proxypass-and-resolver.html).

Comment: Thank you very much. I stuck with this issue a while.

Answer (score 2):

I would try to go for something like:

```
 server_name *.mydomain.com;

 ...
 location / {
   proxy_pass $scheme://$host.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com$request_uri
 }
```

Someone here has done a great job describing in depth all the details needed

https://serverfault.com/questions/706438/what-is-the-difference-between-nginx-variables-host-http-host-and-server-na

Answer (score 0):

You can use `access_by_lua` (or `access_by_lua_file`) to set a variable which you can then use in the `proxy_pass` directive.

Here's a snippet from my PoC `nginx.conf`:

```
# Default upstream variable; blank is the best option *in my case*.
set $upstream '';
# Run the script to figure out the required upstream.
access_by_lua_file upstream.lua;
# The script sets the $upstream variable for this request.
proxy_pass http://$upstream;
```

And the relevant bit from `upstream.lua`:

```
-- 'val' is set by business rules
-- (left as an exercise for the reader)
ngx.var.upstream = val
```